# Flutter - image picker issue at release apk

Tags: flutter, dart

i am a newbe at programming, i am very interested in flutter(dart).
Now i am facing my first big problem and i hope someone can help me out.
I would like use the flutter image picker pakage to get a image from my gallary or camera and show my users on the screen. So far so good and it works on emulator, also on my device but just if its connected to my pc, but if i build a release apk and send it to any device it doesent work. Watch at the videos.

Here it works:

https://streamable.com/3nj93j

Here the release apk Version

https://streamable.com/ba7eil

What i tried:
I have found few similar problams and i thounght it is a storage problem, i used:
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
but it doesent help, also i tried set the sdk from 30 to 28, nothing helps

Update: I build the app-debug.apk and send it to my device, it works fine.
I dont get it why the app-relase.apk ist not working???

Here my Methode:

```
  Future getImage() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

I hope anyone have a idea

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale de-AT)
• Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\Flutter\flutter
• Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (3 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
• Engine revision 2f0af37152
• Dart version 2.10.5

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:/Users/acas1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/acas1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 193.7547
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• SM F916B (mobile) • R3CN80VJP2V • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30)

Comment: Is it still not working? 
did you update to flutter 2.0 or above and tried?

Comment: still the same problem